# How to fix method printing null for some iterations?

Tags: file, bufferedreader, filereader

Write a program that shall calculate the vocabulary richness of a text in a file and the frequency of the most common word. The vocabulary richness is the number of words in the text divided by the number of distinct words. The frequency of a word is the number of times the word is mentioned in the text divided by the total number of words in the text.

Define and implement class `WordCounter` with two private fields String word and int count, constructor `WordCounter(String word)`, and public methods `String getName()`, `int getCount()`, and `void addToCounter()`.

Define and implement class `Corpus` (as in text corpus) with one private field `ArrayList<WordCounter>` words, constructor `Corpus(BufferedReader infile)`, and public methods `double getVocabularyRichness()` and `String getMostFrequentWord()`.

Implement a test program (as the public static void main method in `Corpus`) that reads all files in a specific folder, creates a `Corpus` object from each (previously opened) file, and saves the requested statistics into another file stats.csv. You can either create a new Corpus object for each file or define an `ArrayList<Corpus>` of the corpora.

Each line of the CSV file must consist of three fields separated by commas (but no spaces!): the file name, the vocabulary richness, and the most frequently used word. Run your program on all Shakespeare's plays. Submit the CSV file together with the Java file.

I wrote what I think is the correct implementation of the HW problem because it works properly for some of the text files, however only the `words.get(i).getName()` (I tested with `words.get(i).getCount()`) method will print a blank space for some of the files. I have tried everything, and can't seem to figure it out. Can you please give me a hint or some guidance as to how to fix this issue?

```
public class Corpus {

    private ArrayList<WordCounter> words = new ArrayList <WordCounter>() ;

    Corpus(BufferedReader infile){
    String ln;
        try {
            while((ln = infile.readLine()) != null) {
                for (String word : ln.toLowerCase().split("([,.\\s]+)")) {
                    int reference = 0;
                    for(int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++) { 
                        if (word.equals(words.get(i).getName())) { 
                            reference++; 
                            words.get(i).addToCounter();
                        } }
                    if (reference==0) { words.add(new WordCounter(word)); }
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } 

    public double getVocabularyRichness() {
        int word_count=0;
        for(int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++) {
            word_count=word_count+words.get(i).getCount();
        }
        return (double)word_count/(double)words.size();

    }
    public String getMostFrequentWord() {
     String winner = "*AN ERROR OCCURRED*";
        int max_count = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++) {
            if(words.get(i).getCount() > max_count){ 
                max_count = words.get(i).getCount(); 
            }
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++) {
            if(words.get(i).getCount() == max_count){ 
                winner = words.get(i).getName();

            }
        }

        //winner="Test " + String.valueOf(words.get(i).getName());;
        //return String.valueOf(max_count);
        return winner;   
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception{
            BufferedWriter writer = null;
            File folder_location = new File("/Users/joaquindelaguardia/Desktop/Shakespeare");
            File[] file_array = folder_location.listFiles();
            for(File iteration_file: file_array) {
                FileReader current_file = new FileReader(iteration_file);
                BufferedReader infile = new BufferedReader(current_file);

                Corpus obj1 = new Corpus(infile);
                String file_name = iteration_file.getName();
                String frequent_word = obj1.getMostFrequentWord();
                String vocabulary_richness = String.valueOf(obj1.getVocabularyRichness());

                System.out.println(file_name);
                System.out.println(frequent_word);
                System.out.println(vocabulary_richness);
                System.out.println("-----------------------------");


                //FileWriter file_writer = new FileWriter("/Users/joaquindelaguardia/Desktop/stats.csv");
                //writer = new BufferedWriter(file_writer);

                //String output = file_name+", "+frequent_word+", "+vocabulary_richness + "\n";

                //writer.append(output);

            }
            //writer.close();

    }

}

public class WordCounter {

    private String word;
    private int count=1;

    WordCounter(String word){
        this.word=word;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return word;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public void addToCounter() {
        count++;
    }
}
```

Im testing the information by printing before appending to file, and as you can see with the small fragment of the output included below, for some cases it prints the most common word (and) while in the second case it doesn't print anything.

shakespeare-lovers-62.txt

and

### 2.2409948542024014

shakespeare-julius-26.txt

### 6.413205537806177